# The confusing derivation in the book 'Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective' by Kevin P. Murphy

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, optimization, derivative

In the section 15.5 of the book 'Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective' by Kevin P. Murphy, it discusses the Gaussian Process Latent Variable Model. The log-likelihood objective function is given By

$$l =  -\frac{D}{2}\ln|K| - \frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(K^{-1}YY^{T})\tag 1$$

Where $K = ZZ^T + \beta^{-1}I$

and the gradient with regard to Z is given by:

$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial \mathbf{Z}_{ij}} = \frac{\partial l}{\partial \mathbf{K}}\frac{\partial \mathbf{K}}{\partial \mathbf{Z}_{ij}}\tag 2$$
and

$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial K} = K^{-1}YY^TK^{-1} - DK^{-1}\tag 3$$

(I think the author omits the '$ \frac{1}{2}$' here).

Anyway, I can get the equation (3) by the rules in [MatrixCookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf). The author then
says we can have

$$\frac{\partial K}{\partial Z} = Z$$

(I think the author omits 2 here)

Finally, we get

$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial Z} = K^{-1}YY^TK^{-1}Z - DK^{-1}Z\tag 4$$

The result matches the result in [Lawrence 2005](https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume6/lawrence05a/lawrence05a.pdf). And
there is a similar derivation in this site, [see the answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286351/gaussian-process-latent-variable-model-optimisation). It seems that the chain rule($$\frac{\partial l}{\partial \mathbf{Z}} = \frac{\partial l}{\partial \mathbf{K}}\frac{\partial \mathbf{K}}{\partial \mathbf{Z}}\tag 5$$) works here.

But as I know, only $$\frac{\partial \text{Tr}[K]}{\partial Z}= 2Z\tag 6$$ and $$\frac{\partial l}{\partial \mathbf{Z}_{ij}} = \text{Tr}\left[\left(\frac{\partial l}{\partial \mathbf{K}}\right)^T\frac{\partial \mathbf{K}}{\partial \mathbf{Z}_{ij}}\right]\tag 7$$. I assume the author omits the'Tr', but How can I get (4) by using (6) and (7).And are there any connections between (5) and (7)? As far as I know, the equation (5) is invalid for matrix-multiplying-shape match.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\d{D}  \def\l{\ell}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\K{K^{-1}}
$First, introduce the extremely useful Frobenius product $(:)\:$
which has the following properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; A^T:B^T \\
{CA}:B &= C:BA^T \;=\; A:C^TB \\
}$$
So part of the answer to your question is that the Frobenius product gets rid of the trace function, so equation $(5)$ should be using the Frobenius product and not a standard matrix product.
Also note that
$K \LR{{\rm as\;well\;as\;}\grad{\l}{K}}$ is a **symmetric** matrix, which simplifies the Frobenius product formulas.
Finally,
$\grad KZ$ is a **fourth-order tensor**, which is a PITA to work with using standard matrix-vector notation.

So, instead of the chain rule (which requires the tensor-valued gradient), use the matrix-valued gradient $\grad{\l}{K}$ to write the differential of $\l,\,$
then change the independent variable from $K\to Z\,$ and formulate the
desired gradient wrt $Z$
$$\eqalign{
d\l &= \frac12\LR{\K YY^T\K-\d\K}:dK \\
   &= \frac12\LR{\K YY^T\K-\d\K}:\LR{Z\:dZ^T + dZ\:Z^T} \\
   &= \LR{\K YY^T\K-\d\K}:\LR{dZ\:Z^T} \\
   &= \LR{\K YY^T\K Z-\d\K Z}:dZ \\
\grad{\l}{Z} &= {\K YY^T\K Z-\d\K Z} \\
}$$